# New hard drive making strange sounds

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a 1 year old WD My Passport 2TB hard drive, but in the past month it has been making strange sounds such as grinding. It still works perfectly fine and I did a disk check on it with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Western Digital has a testing app for Windows.  This allows for detailed testing of their hardware

[Data Lifeguard Diagnostic for Windows](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=3&lang=en)

Comment: It said nothing was wrong with the drive. But I am still wondering why it is making those sounds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm recommend you to use smartctl tool to check you hard drive health